# Missing device drivers cause Windows 7 64bit AHCI install fail

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, installation

When trying to install Windows 7 Professional 64bit SP1, after the language select and click "Install", I get the missing drivers message. I don't have the exact wording, but it's along the lines of:

> device drivers are missing for storage devices, please insert media and browse to driver location.

This happens at the beginning of install.

- The processor is an ASUS P8P67 Rev. B3
- I have tried all the drivers from disk provided with the motherboard, no luck.
- In the BIOS, I have tried, RAID, AHCI and IDE, all with no luck.
- The BIOS shows that I have two 500GB HDDs, and diskpart in the Windows installer shows me the same.

I have tried all the SATA connectors (White SATA 3) (Light Blue SATA 2) and (dark blue marvell SATA 3) but still have no clue.

Comment: IDE mode in the bios should get it installed, are you sure you saved the changes when exiting the bios?, also be sure the sata port the hard drive is on is enabled, some bios's have the ability to disable sata ports individually. Please post he motherboard model and revision numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that trying to install it from a USB configured by a Microsoft application to be bootable and allow the installer to run was causing a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your hard drives are using the GUID Partition Table (GPT) instead of the MBR/Basic one. 
If there are already any partitions on then (and u don't need the info on them if any) delete them using the diskpart utility (<kbd>Shift+F10</kbd>). 
Or try activating UEFI Boot.